# Version control of linux configuration: /etc and installed packages

Tags: linux, git, server, configuration-management

I search a software to track the changes made to linux server configuration.

## Goal

If there is something wrong with the server I want to see the last configuration changes.

## Needed features

- Keep /etc/ in version control
- List of installed packages and their versions. Needs to support dpkg and rpm.
- Auto-commit the changes every hour.
- Maybe: bash-History of user root.

## Not needed

- Configuration management: This is a different topic.
- Restore: I just want a history. Restore is done by hand or configuration management.

Comment: For the first piece, [etckeeper](https://github.com/joeyh/etckeeper) might be a good candidate. For packages, just a raw idea: dump package info before/after installs/updates/removals, diff the output, and put that into some repo (e.g. Apache with DAVSVN and auto-commit). For more specific recommendations, you'd need to add the package system used (RPM, DEB, …).

Comment: @Izzy yes, etckeeper looks nice. AFAIK it does not dump package info. For me this is a valid answer, if you write your comment as answer, I will upvote it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first piece, **[etckeeper](https://github.com/joeyh/etckeeper)** might be a good candidate:

> etckeeper is a collection of tools to let /etc be stored in a git, mercurial, bazaar or darcs repository. This lets you use git to review or revert changes that were made to /etc. Or even push the repository elsewhere for backups or cherry-picking configuration changes.
>
> It hooks into package managers like apt to automatically commit changes made to `/etc` during package upgrades. It tracks file metadata that git does not normally support, but that is important for `/etc`, such as the permissions of `/etc/shadow`.
>
> It's quite modular and configurable, while also being simple to use if you understand the basics of working with version control.

I've never used it myself,<sup>1</sup> so I cannot say how well it meets your overall goal. As its description points out it *hooks into package managers* it might well be there is a way to cover tracking package changes as well. Worth noting, however: *etckeeper* is available via several distributions' repositories, e.g. for Debian and Ubuntu.

Further pointers worth checking:

- [etckeeper Ubuntu documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/etckeeper.html)
- [How To Manage /etc with Version Control Using Etckeeper on CentOS 7](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-manage-etc-with-version-control-using-etckeeper-on-centos-7) (4/2015; incl. prerequisites, installation, configuration, usage)
- SU: [Is it a good idea to use git for configuration file version controlling?](https://superuser.com/q/1037211/143340): [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1037600/143340) says "Yes" and introduces *etckeeper*

---

<sup><sup>1</sup></sup> <sub>I've just read about it in some blogs a while ago, which is how I know about it</sub>

Comment: yes, etckeeper looks like the right tool.... Nevertheless I wait until accepting it. Maybe there are other tools with a different strategy.

Comment: Fair enough. Though you can always move your "accept mark" to another answer, if a better one comes up – so you can't forget to accept anything :)